# Commas in between each character in CSV

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv

I am trying to save my list directly as is to a csv file, but when I open the csv file, it appears with commas between each character.

My list I am trying to save is ['BUD', 'ABBV', 'MO', 'WEED.TO', 'TAP', 'CGC', 'ACB'].

```
def cannabisTickers():
    if __name__ == '__main__':
        resp = requests.get('https://finance.yahoo.com/u/yahoo-finance/watchlists/420_stocks/',
                            headers={
                                'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:68.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/68.0'
                            })
        assert '<table class="cwl-symbols' in resp.text
        soup = BeautifulSoup(resp.text, 'html.parser')
        table = soup.select_one('.cwl-symbols')
        tickers = []
        for row in table.select('tr'):
            ticker = [cell.text for cell in row.select('td')]
            if ticker:
                tickers.append(ticker[0])
    with open('cannabisTickers', 'w') as csvFile:
        writer = csv.writer(csvFile)
        writer.writerows(tickers)
    csvFile.close()
    print(tickers)
```

The csv appears as

```
B,U,D
A,B,B,V
M,O
```

Answer (score 5):

Since `tickers` is a list of strings, each string is taken as a list of characters and saved in the csv when you do `writer.writerows(tickers)`, so `BUD` becomes `['B,'U','D']` and so on

This causes `['BUD', 'ABBV', 'MO', 'WEED.TO', 'TAP', 'CGC', 'ACB']` to become `[['B', 'U', 'D'], ['A', 'B', 'B', 'V'], ['M', 'O'], ['W', 'E', 'E', 'D', '.', 'T', 'O'], ['T', 'A', 'P'], ['C', 'G', 'C'], ['A', 'C', 'B']]` and being saved as such.

Hence you want to pass a list of lists of [writer.writerows](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#csv.csvwriter.writerows), or pass the list to [writer.writerow](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#csv.csvwriter.writerow).

So assuming `tickers = ['BUD', 'ABBV', 'MO', 'WEED.TO', 'TAP', 'CGC', 'ACB']`, instead of

```
writer.writerows(tickers)
```

You want to do

```
writer.writerows([tickers])
```

or

```
writer.writerow(tickers)
```

The csv will then look like

```
BUD,ABBV,MO,WEED.TO,TAP,CGC,ACB
```

Comment: Or just `writer.writerow(tickers)`.

Answer (score 1):

Well, you could simply use primitive file write operation for that, since a `.csv` doesn't have any special encoding with it, therefore we can access/stored data inside a `.csv` as if it's a regular text file.

```
data = ['BUD', 'ABBV', 'MO', 'WEED.TO', 'TAP', 'CGC', 'ACB']

a = "".join([x + "," for x in data])[:-1]

open('cannabisTickers', 'w+').write(a)
```

**Output CSV file:-**

```
BUD,ABBV,MO,WEED.TO,TAP,CGC,ACB
```

I tend to prefer the above method, as it doesn't involves import of modules, uses primitive file handing and therefore is considerably faster.

Comment: This should work unless theres a `"`, `,` or `\n` in the data.

Comment: @KlausD. Well, according to [RFC 4180](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc4180.html), ***Fields containing line breaks, double quotes, and commas should be enclosed in double-quotes***, i.e if the data contains such characters, then they should/could be enclosed inside double quotes. ex. `a = r'"after, today"'` (included the r, to prevent unicode decode error, if the character is `\n`). This is done to ensure that database management software (like *excel*) doesn't consider the data containing one of the above characters as an  *delimeter*. So these characters will also work, if enclosed in `"`